# Php object remanent between script run

Tags: php

I want to make a certain object 'static' between different runs of the php script, in order to optimize the performance of my scripts and avoid the initialization hit which is heavy.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Why not to use cache ? ACP could be useful.

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php+apc first hit (or third for wikipedia).

Comment: @joksnet: I think you mean APC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it into the user's session. Make sure, though, that the class is declared before session_start():

```
require 'heavy_class.php';
session_start();

$_SESSION['heavy'] = new HeavyClass;
```

Comment: looking nice. I will try this method and answer back when I see the impact.

Comment: Works fine, however it is actually slightly worse, looks like my init time is lower than serialize / deserialize approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the object and then persist it to either a local file or a database.  This is best done using the php function `serialize()`

You then use `unserialize()` to restore the object.

There are some "gotchas" such that the object's class must be available to the executing script.

This will call the magic methods on the object being serialized `__sleep()` and `__wakeup` when it is serialized and unserialized respectively.  Any database initialization should happen in these methods.

Link to the php docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: +1 so I could address all the session solutions at once: Session will create LESS objects, but not a SINGLE object. If the goal is to have one single object, you need to do something else. Since session is user specific.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize that object and store it in session :).
In order to use it again user unserialize.

Answer (score 1):

Stick it in a session, it will serialize it for you automatically.  You can use the __wakeup and __sleep magic methods to handle any database connections and such, but you can avoid disk hits.